# VBA text to columns only one element

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have data cells like this in my excel spreadsheet:
CZ15.cbt,411.00,"4/2/2015","2:30pm",+4.25,406.75,412.25,403.25,36155

The only thing I am interested in is the second element, i.e. 411.00. Is their a way to copy **only** this value in another cell?

So far I used this code:

```
Worksheets("Workspace").Range("A1").texttocolumns Destination:=Worksheets("Workspace").Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                                     Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1))
```

This copies all the elements in cells next to each other, and then I just referenced the second element into the result worksheet. The problem is that now I have multiple cells next to each other with the original 9 elements, and they would overwrite each other.

Another option would be to copy the 9 elements vertically, so that they are all in the same column. Whichever is easier...

Thank you very much!
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Use *Split()*:

```
Sub Stefan()
    ary = Split(Worksheets("Workspace").Range("A1").Value, ",")
    Worksheets("Workspace").Range("B1") = ary(1)
End Sub
```

This creates an *Array* and you use only the second element.

**EDIT#1:**

To do this for more than one cell we use a loop:

```
Sub Stefan()
    For i = 1 To 6
        ary = Split(Worksheets("Workspace").Range("A" & i).Value, ",")
        Worksheets("Workspace").Range("B" & i) = ary(1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This gives me the following error:

Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range.

Maybe a minor typo?

Comment: @StefanW   It is telling us that it cannot find a comma in the text in cell **A1**

Comment: My bad, I am sorry. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you help me slightly modifying it so that it does the same for cells A1 to A6? What do I have Range("A2") to replace with?

    ary = Split(Worksheets("Workspace").Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value, ",")
    Worksheets("Workspace").Range("A2") = ary(1)

Answer (score 0):

A formula might suit:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-FIND(",",A1)-1)
```

[MID](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php)
[FIND](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php)

FIND is used to locate the first comma and also the first comma after the first comma and then their distance apart. Between these two MID extracts the characters.

Comment: The latter; trying to parse that formula is making me physically ill